# c# Regular Expression for the text below?

Tags: c#, regex

I have strings of array.

One of the strings:

> myText = "[Date].[Hierarchy].[Year].&[2005].&[Q1].&[Jan]"

The `[Date].[Hierarchy].[Year].&` part is always the same, but the rest is changing depending on the today date.

So it would be for today like `[Date].[Hierarchy].[Year].&[2013].&[Q3].&[Jul]`, but in the array I also have other strings that like `[Date].[Hierarchy].[Year].&[2005].&[Q1].&[Jan].&[20]`.

The regex should opt those out also.

I am only interested in strings from array like `[Date].[Hierarchy].[Year].&[2005].&[Q1].&[Jan]", [Date].[Hierarchy].[Year].&[2005].&[Q1].&[Feb], [Date].[Hierarchy].[Year].&[2005].&[Q1].&[Mar], ...`.

I hope you get the pattern.

Comment: I can get the pattern but it takes all the strings ends with [Date].[Hierarchy].[Year].&[2005].&[Q1].&[Jan].&[20] too. I dont know how to opt them out. the pattern should return false for those strings

Comment: Please post your pattern so we can work with something.

Comment: I cannot escape [  character. can you just please tell me how I can represent [Date]. pattern in a text? then I can do the rest I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `Regex` should do it. The year is currently set to 4 digits, if you only want it to match 2005, replace the `\d{4}` bit.

```
^\[Date\]\.\[Hierarchy\]\.\[Year\]\.&\[\d{4}\]\.&\[Q1\]\.&\[[A-Z-a-z]{3}\]$
```

Here's the result:

```
   [Date].[Hierarchy].[Year].&[2005].&[Q1].&[Jan] // matches
   [Date].[Hierarchy].[Year].&[2013].&[Q3].&[Jul] // no match
   [Date].[Hierarchy].[Year].&[2005].&[Q1].&[Jan].&[20] // no match
```

Edit to your comment: Make sure you put an @ before the string declaration.

```
 var pattern = new Regex(@"^\[Date\]\.\[Hierarchy\]\.\[Year\]\.&\[\d{4}\]\.&\[Q1\]\.&\[[A-Z-a-z]{3}\]$");
      var matches = pattern.IsMatch("[Date].[Hierarchy].[Year].&[2005].&[Q1].&[Jan]");
```

Comment: Thank you ver much. Sorry I am new to C# and when I use your pattern I assign it to a text in quotation marks and it tells me bad compile constant value. I am not sure whether I should pass that pattern to a class method or not then I used   string sPattern = "^"+Regex.Escape("[") + "Date]."+Regex.Escape("[")+"Hierarchy]."+Regex.Escape("[")+"Year].&"+Regex.Escape("[")+"\\d{4}].&"+Regex.Escape("[")+"Q\\d{1}].&"+Regex.Escape("[")+"\\w{3}]$"; instead and it did the job. But I am also wondering how I could use your pattern directly in my code?

Comment: @akdurmus Edit added for clarification.